# read a file line by line and print only after its done

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

So I am working on doing a "simple" task since like 2h and still can't find the solution, so where is my question :
I want to search in a file, line by line, and if no result is found, at the end print something, else call a function.

```
def DeletItemCheckUp():
    import re
    find = True
    itemNumber = input("\n what is the item you want to delet : ")
    fileItem = open('Data_Item', 'r', encoding='Utf-8')
    for line in fileItem:
        sr = re.search(r'^\b%s\b'%itemNumber,(line.split(';')[0]))
        if (sr == None):
            pass
    print("This item don't exist.")
    fileItem.close()
    if (find == True):
        return itemNumber
        DeletItem()
```

so here is the problem I have got with different try :
 1. Print "This item don't exist." for every line that didn't had my itemNumber.
 2. When there was actually no match found, its would not call DeletItem().

objectif of the code :
Ask for a item to delet, check in a file if the unique item number exist, if so, call DeletItem() to delet it, else, tell the user that this unique item number don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few overlooks in there to achieve what you ask. We are going to use a flag (true/false) to know when we found something, and based on that we will decide whether to call the function or print/return the number.

```
def DeletItemCheckUp():
    import re
    find = False      # initialize to False
    itemNumber = input("\n what is the item you want to delet : ")
    fileItem = open('Data_Item', 'r', encoding='Utf-8')
    for line in fileItem:
        sr = re.search(r'^\b%s\b'%itemNumber,(line.split(';')[0]))
        if (sr == None):
            continue  # do nothing and continue
        else:
            # we found the number, set the flag and break
            find = True
            break  # no need to continue searching
    fileItem.close()
    if (find):
        DeletItem()           # call the function
    else:
        print("This item don't exist.")
```

Comment: That work perfectly, thanks for saving me more hours trying to find out how to do that haha! =)

Answer (score 0):

1) replace the pass with your print('This item doesn't exist'). "Pass" means "do nothing."

2) Your DeleteItem() is *after* the return. Nothing executes after the return because you have returned to the place the function was called from. You want

```
else:
    DeleteItem()
```